# could not process input request on the Proton server, the input stream is down due to:invalid stream header: 504F5354

Tags: fiware-orion, complex-event-processing

I have deployed Proton and a docker image of Orion in the same Ubuntu server.

When Orion is sending events to Proton I'm getting the following failure

```
PM com.ibm.hrl.proton.server.adapter.eventHandlers.RequestHandler run
INFO: run: could not process input request on the Proton server, the input stream is down due to:invalid stream header: 504F5354
```

My server is running Ubuntu 14.04, tomcat7 and java  8

And the subscription sent to Orion to get events to Proton is the following

```
(curl 192.168.90.3:1026/v1/subscribeContext?notifyFormat=xml -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service: ct_stc' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "STCSensor",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "605222424"
        }
    ],
    "reference": "http://192.168.90.3:3002/ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "Serial",
                "BatteryLevel",
                "CurrentRSSI",
                "LastPacketRSSI",
                "LastPacketSNR",
                "OzoneCal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

Adding POST similar to the one received by Proton

```
POST /test/xml.php HTTP/1.1" 200 168 "-" "orion/0.24.0-next libcurl/7.19.7
<notifyContextRequest>
  <subscriptionId>56279a61e4ea5f2df9a9eebc</subscriptionId>
  <originator>localhost</originator>
  <contextResponseList>
    <contextElementResponse>
      <contextElement>
        <entityId type="STCSensor" isPattern="false">
          <id>605222424</id>
        </entityId>
        <contextAttributeList>
          <contextAttribute>
            <name>Altitude</name>
            <type>integer</type>
            <contextValue>720</contextValue>
          </contextAttribute>
...
```

And logs in Orion

```
orion_1 | INFO@14:40:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[199]: Starting transaction to 192.168.90.3:3002/ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events
orion_1 | INFO@14:40:04  connectionOperations.cpp[307]: Database Operation Successful (insert: { _id: ObjectId('5627a3c4e4ea5f2df9a9eebe'), expiration: 1448030404, reference: "http://192.168.90.3:3002/ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events", throttling: 1, servicePath: "/#", entities: [ { id: "705222424", type: "STCSensor", isPattern: "false" } ], attrs: [], conditions: [ { type: "ONCHANGE", value: [ "Serial", "BatteryLevel", "CurrentRSSI", "LastPacketRSSI", "LastPacketSNR"] } ], lastNotification: 1445438404, count: 1, format: "XML" })
orion_1 | INFO@14:40:04  rest.cpp[467]: Transaction ended
orion_1 | WARNING@14:40:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[435]: Notification failure for 192.168.90.3:3002 (curl_easy_perform failed: Failure when receiving data from the peer)
orion_1 | INFO@14:40:04  httpRequestSend.cpp[452]: Transaction ended
```

Is anything wrong in the subscription?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is the request sent by orion POST /test/xml.php HTTP/1.1" 200 168 "-" "orion/0.24.0-next libcurl/7.19.7"

Comment: Is 192.168.90.3:3002 reachable from inside the Orion container?

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually both servers are deployed in the same host. In xml received by Proton you can see that the originator is localhost. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the same host? They are both on the same container? one container each and both on localhost?

Comment: One container each and both on Locahost